# python snap7 on Anaconda for windows 10 - can't find snap7 library

Tags: python, anaconda3, siemens, s7-1200, snap7

I try to use snap7 (to read from a S7-1200) python 3.8 on Anaconda for Windows 10 .I have followed many suggestions on this issue. However, I cannot solve this problem.

```
import snap7

plc = snap7.client.Client()
```

> Snap7Exception: can't find snap7 library. If installed, try running
> ldconfig

If you have any suggestion for this problem i'd appreaciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the snap7 library using conda?

conda install python-snap7

If you are using conda as your package installer then using the above command will be the way to go. Reference the snap7 library on https://pypi.org/project/python-snap7/